# Spring exception handler , can't access request attributes

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

I have this controller using spring boot 2.1

```
@Controller
@AllArgsConstructor
@ControllerAdvice
public class AdminPoolsController {

@PostMapping("admin/pools/edit")
    public String update(@Valid final PoolDto pool,
                         @RequestParam(name = "image-upload", required = false) final MultipartFile file,
                         final BindingResult bindingResult,
                         final RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) throws IOException {
        //some logic
    }


    @ExceptionHandler(MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class)
    public String fileSizeLimitExc(
            final HttpServletRequest request,
            final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
            final MaxUploadSizeExceededException exc
    ) {
        final Object id = request.getAttribute("id");
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(
                "errors",
                ImmutableMap.of(
                        "logo",
                        String.format(
                                "File exceeded max size of %d bytes",
                                exc.getMaxUploadSize()
                        )
                )
        );
        return "redirect:/admin/pools/edit" + (id == null ? "" : "?id=" + id.toString());
    }

}
```

As you see I have PoolDto in POST method , this DTO has id , binding happen through html form

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" th:value="${pool.id}">
```

In html form I can provide file using input type file , but this file is limited in size therefore I catch **MaxUploadSizeExceededException** 
My problem is , **HttpServletRequest** inside error handling method doesn't have any request attributes , in my case I want to get **id** from original request , but it is always null. How can I catch original request attributes using ExceptionHandler ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a request hits the maximum upload size, the request body is never fully processed. Instead, it is cancelled when the limit is reached. Therefore, data transmitted in the request body is not available. That is not related to Spring Boot. It's a more fundamental restriction.

To pass some ID, you basically have three options:

1. Put the ID in the URL, e.g. `admin/pool/edit/123` or `admin/pool/edit?id=123`
2. Store the ID in a cookie.
3. Store the ID in the session. The session ID is retained via a cookie.

Comment: Thank you , i have used your solution but without cookie , I will post my solution

Answer (score 1):

may be it could help:

```
@Controller
@AllArgsConstructor
@ControllerAdvice
public class AdminPoolsController {

@PostMapping("admin/pools/edit")
    public String update(@Valid final PoolDto pool,
                         @RequestParam(name = "image-upload", required = false) final MultipartFile file,
                         final BindingResult bindingResult,
                         final RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs,HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        //some logic

           // set it before throwing MaxUploadSizeExceededException  
           request.setAttribute("id",pool.getId());

    }


    @ExceptionHandler(MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class)
    public String fileSizeLimitExc(
            final HttpServletRequest request,
            final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
            final MaxUploadSizeExceededException exc
    ) {
        final Object id = request.getAttribute("id");
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(
                "errors",
                ImmutableMap.of(
                        "logo",
                        String.format(
                                "File exceeded max size of %d bytes",
                                exc.getMaxUploadSize()
                        )
                )
        );
        return "redirect:/admin/pools/edit" + (id == null ? "" : "?id=" + id.toString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Codo said it's not possible to store request body therefore I have used his solution with GET param **?id=123** but I don't store it in cookies instead I use **refer** header , this is my solution

```
private static final Pattern ID_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\?id=([0-9]+)");

@ExceptionHandler(MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class)
    public String fileSizeLimitExc(
            final NativeWebRequest request,
            final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
            final MaxUploadSizeExceededException exc
    ) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(
                "errors",
                ImmutableMap.of(
                        "logo",
                        String.format(
                                "File exceeded max size of %d bytes",
                                ((FileUploadBase.FileSizeLimitExceededException) exc.getCause().getCause()).getActualSize()
                        )
                )
        );

        final StringBuilder redirectUrl = new StringBuilder("redirect:/admin/pools/edit");
        this.poolId(request).ifPresent(id -> redirectUrl.append("?id=").append(id));
        return redirectUrl.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Get pool id from exception handler method
     *
     * @param request Native request
     * @return Pool id if present
     */
    private Optional<String> poolId(final NativeWebRequest request) {
        final String referer = request.getHeader("referer");
        final Matcher matcher = ID_PATTERN.matcher(referer);

        final Optional<String> id;
        if (matcher.find()) {
            id = Optional.of(matcher.group(1));
        } else {
            id = Optional.empty();
        }
        return id;
    }
```